# lookup column in sharepoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, modern-experience, quick-edit

[image]

I have sharepoint list where we have lookup column which is not loading the data(options) related.

Anyone has idea how to resolve it.

This is working fine in classic mode.

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot or something? How you have configured your lookup column? How it is in Modern page?

Comment: i have added config of lookup column, when we change list in quick edit mode  and try to get data in column it keep on loading. but same works in classic mode

Comment: How many list items are there in parent list from where you have added a lookup column?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message showing when "lookup column not loading the data(options) related." 
Did you see something like this? Or any other error message?

[image]

Please provide more information about your parent list and the child list so we can do more tests about your issue.